# New view does not appear in the browser.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC.NET, using aspx view engine. I have created a new view, at visual studio, under HOME directory named jobs.aspx.

When I go to properties, it shows "`Browse to URL: ~/Home/jobs`".

But When I add

`Localhost:port/Home/jobs` at the browser I get 404 error.

While `Localhost:port/Home` works normally.

Do you know how I can fix that?

Thanks

Comment: In reply to your removed comment: I think your question is downvoted because from our perspective you are missing some basic knowledge about ASP.NET MVC. As SethMW posted in his answer below, it looks you're missing an `ActionResult` in your controller, which is a pretty basic thing in MVC and one of the first things you will learn when reading a tutorial. However, if you do have an `ActionResult` things will get different and you should update your question together with some code.

Comment: *“Who the hell is playing the role of Hitler here, deletes my comments, and downvotes my questions?”* You’re overreacting just a little. I’d go so far as to say you’re being a bit rude. In fact, that could be another reason why your question got downvoted and your comments got deleted.

Comment: @minitech Hi minitech. Why do you think that? Do you think that deleting the comments of the person who asks a question, is moral? Instead of getting a reason why someone is not happy with my question and downvotes it, when I post a comment, he/she also deletes that. I do not think this is absolutely right, nor helpful...

Comment: I absolutely think it’s moral, given how absolutely impolite you were being. If you disagree with our voting system (which is working as intended, I might add), please feel free to make suggestions on [Meta].

Comment: @minitech I do not think that my question was impolite, or my comments...except from the very last one, which was posted by me when I saw my comments being deleted as well, and was deleted by me seconds after. And in addition, the first think I learned as an instructor is that "There are no stupid questions. You should answer them as the person who asks them, clearly does not understand something", which is definitely not the way the community here is thinking...

Comment: Hi John If u r new to MVC I will suggest you the book from Rick Anderson and Scott Hanselman. http://freecomputerbooks.com/Intro-to-ASP.NET-MVC-4-with-Visual-Studio.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Jobs() action to your HomeController.cs to complete the loop. Notice the Index() action in that class.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SethMW's answer.

Go to your `HomeController` class and add `ActionResult` that will return a `View`.

This action result should be called `Jobs()` and may return a specific or default view.

```
public ActionResult Jobs() 
{
   return View();
   //return View("NameOfDesiredView");
}
```

Also if you are getting started with MVC I suggest you to learn the `Razor` syntax rather than the outdated `aspx` view engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mtashev. You have just got my +1